# Laravel laravel-echo-server not receiving messages (chat)

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, websocket, laravel-echo

I'm trying to setup [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) but I can't get it to work. With the same setup (I use Vue.js) it's working with [pusher](https://pusher.com). I have build a chat.

My `laravel-echo-server.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "authHost": "https://sayhidog.test",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {}
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "/Users/lars/.config/valet/Certificates/sayhidog.test.crt",
    "sslKeyPath": "/Users/lars/.config/valet/Certificates/sayhidog.test.key",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

When I run `laravel-echo-server start` I see:

[image]

This looks great, when I send a message I see:

[image]

In vue.js I connect like this:

```
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

    if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
        window.Echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
        });
    }
```

And I listen like this:

```
window.Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
        this.messages.push({
            body: e.message.body,
            user: e.user
        });
    });
```

My channels.php looks like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

In my Controller I broadcast:

```
broadcast(new MessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();
```

The MessageSent looks like this:

```
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
/**
 * User that sent the message
 *
 * @var User
 */
public $user;

/**
 * Message details
 *
 * @var ChatMessage
 */
public $message;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @param ChatMessage $message
 */
public function __construct(User $user, ChatMessage $message)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->message = $message;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
}
```

}

The connection in my network tab looks fine:

[image]

I don't get any new messages in my chat. With pusher it's working. What could I be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: can you share vuejs code of listen to chat channel ?

Comment: @AhmedAtoui I've updated my question :)

Comment: are you want using pusher or socket.io?,as i see you want connect with pusher but in vue code you are using socketIo lib!

Comment: @AhmedAtoui I have used pusher now I want to use socket.io but that is not working

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define method on your MessageSent channel named broadcastAs and it return custom name like this:

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'message.sent';
}
```

then listen to this event with custom name you have choose and prepend with dot (.) like this:

```
window.Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('.message.sent', (e) => {
        this.messages.push({
            body: e.message.body,
            user: e.user
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I add this I still won't receive any messages. @AhmedAtoui

Answer (score 2):

Try add this line in .env file, this solved my problem:

```
REDIS_PREFIX=
```

[Why laravel broadcast channel has a prefix? #28210](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28210)

Answer (score 1):

Check your package.json to make sure you have installed socket.io-client version 2.3.0.  Currently (Jan 2021) version 3.0 will not work, as I have spent many hours discovering.